# Find a maximum matching

Tags: algorithm, graph, computer-science

> Let `G(A,B,V)`, a bipartite graph where `|A|=|B|=n`. There's a matching, `M` subset of `E` where `|M| = n-2013`. Describe an efficient algorithm to determine if a maximal matching exists.

Basically the given solution is building a flow-network from the graph, by adding `s,t` vertices, connecting `s` to each vertex `v` in `A` and each vertex `v` in `B` to `t`. All capacities are `1`.

Now, we give a starting flow for all edges `M` (And all edges connected to edges of `M`, from `s` and to `t`)

Now we just need to run Fold-Falkerson (or Edmond-Karp) Algorithm and check if we were able to improve `2013` paths (i.e. adding more flow for some path). More precisely, **we need, at most, to run BFS, `2013`  times to decide**

My question is:
Why does it work? As I see it, `M` is just an arbitrary match. It's like we are assuming that `M` is part of a maximal-matching.

I'd be glad for a clarification!

Thanks

Comment: Is your question to find whether a maximal matching exists that includes M?

Comment: No, just whether or not a maximal matching exists (with the size of $n$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, the algorithms is this:

1. Create the flow network *s → A → B → t*
2. On this network, calculate the flow induced by *M*.
3. Now create the [residual flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network#Residuals), and continue Edmonds-Karp from here.

Why does this work? The [Ford-Fulkerson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) guarantees that, given *any* valid flow (in particular, in this case the one given by *M*, while the maximal flow is not yet achieved, there is an augmenting path in the residual network. Here, each augmentation increases the flow (and hence the matching) by 1. Hence, if the maximal flow is *q*, then within *q - |M|* iterations, it will be achieved.

The point which seems to confuse you is that it seems that the optimal matching necessarily includes *M*. This is not the case. Augmentation along the residual network can actually *cancel* flows in the original network. Hence, the augmentations can actually "reverse" some of the matchings of *M*.

Comment: Oh I see now. Cancellation includes finding a new augmenting path.